# In CSS or SASS, is using "#foo #bar { width: 200px }" not recommended for increased file size?

Tags: css, sass

Short question is: is the following (an id under another id) not recommended for bloating up the CSS file size?

```
#product-box #product-photo { width: 200px }
```

---

details:

Sometimes in SASS, we might have

```
#product-box

  margin-top: 20px

  #product-photo
    width: 200px
```

this way, it means it is "nested" -- that is, `#product-photo`'s style of width 200px is only true within `#product-box`, and the CSS generated from the SASS is

```
#product-box { margin-top: 20px }
#product-box #product-photo { width: 200px }
```

but here we have a redundant `#product-box` before `#product-photo`, because `#product-photo` by itself can uniquely identify the element already.

As a result, the CSS file can become bloated.  I wonder if it is recommended to un-indent `#product-photo` in the SASS file, so that it doesn't need to be nested?

I think we could have a `.photo` class inside `#product-box` instead... is it true?  But in some cases, we might have 2 photos, or 2 `li` inside a `#product-box`, and so using a class cannot uniquely identify an element.  If we use jQuery, it is true we can say `$('#product-box li:eq(2)` to get to any element, but it may introduce bug if somebody add another `li` without knowing the jQuery code depends on it.  Having an `id` will prevent such bug from happening.

Answer (score 6):

if you're selecting an element by its id, you don't need to have a nested selector - the id has to be uique everytime. if you have a class that has a different style depending on it's parent, you have to use such a nestes selector (but, if a class has the same style in every case, you can drop the parent-selector, too).

example:

```
#product-box #product-photo { width: 200px }
```

is the same as

```
#product-photo { width: 200px }
```

you could also use a class for that:

```
.photo { width: 200px }
```

**but:** if a photo has a different size in some cases, you have to do something like this:

```
#product-box .photo { width: 200px }
#another-box .photo { width: 150px }
```

or, alternatively, define a "default" and a special case:

```
.photo { width: 200px } // the default
#another-box .photo { width: 150px } // special size for photos inside #another-box
```

**note:** i have no idea how to do this in sass (i have no idea what sass *is*), but i hope this is helping you anyway.

**note2:** you shouldn't worry about this small effect on the css file-size until you have realy, realy, realy much traffic on your site - it's much more important that everything is readable and easy to understand, otherwise you will get in hell if you have to change something in the future (also, if you wan't to decrease you filesize as much as possible, why do you use such long ids? for breaking that down, wouldn't it be the best to use `#a` `#b` `#c` `#d`... and so on?)

Comment: hm, the longer name is for readability... I want to use good names, but don't want to use redundant nested IDs...  by the way, maybe high traffic or not, if the load time of the page is reduced, then the user experience is improved, which might bring in more visitor return and word of mouth recommendations

Comment: IDs are only unique on a per-page basis. If you're serving the same stylesheets to many page templates, there are times when it might be appropriate to nest IDs. In general, you should try to keep nesting to a minimum.